# How to vectorize my code which runs on row iteration?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a code that will list the total amount of time that a record with a specific value is found next to each other as shown in the attached picture:

[image: Dataframe]

I have written the following code and it works fine:

```
bit= False
    exe= True
    x= len(df)
    for i in range (x):
        #Reset bit if type not Residential
        if df.loc[i,'type'] != 'Residential':
            bit= False
        #Duplicate data if type same
        if bit and i != 0:
            df.loc[i,'Test']= df.loc[(i-1),'Test']

        #Finding max row for specific row
        if not bit and df.loc[i,'type']=='Residential':
            counter=0
            k= i
            while df.loc[k,'type']=='Residential' and exe:
                bit= True
                counter += 1
                df.loc[i,'Test'] = counter
                df.loc[i,'MaxTimeStamp']=df.loc[k,'price']
                if k < (x-1):
                    k += 1
                else:
                    exe= False
```

However, when I am running it in a large dataframe, the run time is very slow. I have read that row iterations are not efficient and it's better to vectorise - but I am not able to vectorise the code above.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste your dataframe in your question as a text instead of an image and include your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that your code is based on rows iteration, but actually the
situation is even worse. Your main loop runs over **row numers** (and
at the same indices) and then, in each turn of your loop, you retrieve individual row, based of this index.
To make the thing worse, your code:

- repeats this retrieval on each access to any element on the "current"
  row (indicated by *i*),
- will fail if the index is something other than consecutive integers,
  starting from *0*.

As I see from your picture of the DataFrame, you actually want to
generate *Test* column with value - **how many times** occured
consecutive rows with *type == 'Residential'* (not the amount of time,
which means rather the difference between e.g. timestamps).

For rows with other values, *Test* column should have an **empty string**.

To do it, you can run

```
df['Test'] = df.groupby((df.type.shift(1) != df.type).cumsum()).type\
    .transform(lambda grp: grp.size if grp.iloc[0] == 'Residential' else '')
```

To check the above code, I prepared a source DataFrame - a copy of only
*type* column from your picture:

```
          type
0  Residential
1  Residential
2  Residential
3  Residential
4  Residential
5        Condo
6  Residential
7  Residential
8        Condo
```

After I ran my code, the result was:

```
          type Test
0  Residential    5
1  Residential    5
2  Residential    5
3  Residential    5
4  Residential    5
5        Condo     
6  Residential    2
7  Residential    2
8        Condo
```

Your code sample sets also values in *MaxTimeStamp* column, but:

- your picture does not contain this column,
- for me it is a weird combination that in column named *MaxTimeStamp*
  you save values from *price* column,
- in your statment of problem you didn't write about this column,

so I left this detail untouched.

It is also worth to notice that the new column is of **object** type,
because not all elements are numbers. If you want this column to be of
e.g. *int* type, change the "else" value from an empty string to some
integer value, e.g. *0* or *-1* (meaning "no data" here).
The *else* value could also be *np.nan* (true "no data" marker),
but then this column would be coerced to *float* type, because
*np.nan* is just a special case of *float*.

## Edit following comments as of 29.08

**Explanation of the solution**

1. Run: `df.type.shift(1)` - it displays *type* value from the **previous** row:

   ```
    0            NaN
    1    Residential
    2    Residential
    3    Residential
    4    Residential
    5    Residential
    6          Condo
    7    Residential
    8    Residential
    Name: type, dtype: object
   ```

   For the first row the result is *NaN* - no data, since for the first row
   there is no previous row.
2. Now run: `df.type.shift(1) != df.type`. It displays a *Series* of *bool*
   type, an answer to the question: Is *type* in previous row other than *type*
   in the current row:

   ```
    0     True
    1    False
    2    False
    3    False
    4    False
    5     True
    6     True
    7    False
    8     True
    Name: type, dtype: bool
   ```

   As you can see, rows with index *0*, *5*, *6* and *8* start a new sequence
   of identical values (compare with *df*).
3. Run: `(df.type.shift(1) != df.type).cumsum()`. The result is:

   ```
    0    1
    1    1
    2    1
    3    1
    4    1
    5    2
    6    3
    7    3
    8    4
    Name: type, dtype: int32
   ```

   Note that rows with index *0* thru *4* (the first group of *Residential*)
   have value of *1*. Then row *5* (*Condo*) has value of *2*.
   The next group, with value of *3* are rows *6* and *7* (*Residential*).
   And finally row *8* has value of *4*.
4. To see the result of grouping, run:

   ```
    gr = df.groupby((df.type.shift(1) != df.type).cumsum())
    for key, grp in gr:
        print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{grp}')
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
    Group: 1
              type
    0  Residential
    1  Residential
    2  Residential
    3  Residential
    4  Residential

    Group: 2
        type
    5  Condo

    Group: 3
              type
    6  Residential
    7  Residential

    Group: 4
        type
    8  Condo
   ```

   so you see the division into groups, just as I described in the previous
   point.
5. To be able to invoke the transformation function individually on each
   group, and see the result, define:

   ```
    trFun = lambda grp: grp.size if grp.iloc[0] == 'Residential' else ''
   ```
6. Then run:

   ```
    for key, grp in gr:
        print(f'{key}: {trFun(gr.get_group(key).type)}')
   ```

   The result is:

   ```
    1: 5
    2: 
    3: 2
    4:
   ```

   Note that *transform* works this way that the returned value is
   **replicated** to all group members, so:

   - each row from group *1* gets *5*,
   - each row from group *2* gets an empty string,
   - each row from group *3* gets *2*,
   - each row from group *4* gets again an empty string.

   And just these values are saved in *Test* column.

**The second question**

This question can be interpreted two ways:

1. How many **rows** in *df* have *type* equal to the previous row.

   Start from a more basic question: **Which rows** have *type* equal
   to the previous row? The answer is:

   ```
    df.type.shift(1) == df.type
   ```

   getting:

   ```
    0    False
    1     True
    2     True
    3     True
    4     True
    5    False
    6    False
    7     True
    8    False
    Name: type, dtype: bool
   ```

   So as you see, they are rows *1* thru *4* and *7*.

   And to answer the original question (**How many...**), run:
   `(df.type.shift(1) == df.type).sum()` getting *5*.
2. How many **groups** of consecutive values in *type* column has
   this DataFrame?

   The answer is: `(df.type.shift(1) != df.type).sum()` getting *4*.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. i have been trying to understand your code, however it seems too difficult to comprehend. I am still new to python. Can you please give a breakdown as to how the code works.

Comment: Also taking it to a new level, is there a way to  generate Test column with value - how many times consecutive rows occur with type[i] == type[i+1], instead of only residential?